# using @font-face rule and only special characters won't show in IE

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I am using @font-face rule, and it works perfectly on chrome and firefox, but when opened in IE it won't read special characters (ć,č,š ..). Is it because of the font-format? I presume the problem is in .eot, but if i remove it, then it won't open in IE at all. Does anyone have any ideas?

Here is my code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'sommet_roundedregular';
    src: url('sommet_rounded_regular.otf'),
         url('sommet_rounded_regular-webfont.eot'),
         url('sommet_rounded_regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('sommet_rounded_regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('sommet_rounded_regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('sommet_rounded_regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),  
         url('sommet_rounded_regular-webfont.svg#sommet_roundedregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use this style

@font-face{

```
font-family:'font1';
src:url('font/B_Titr_Bold.eot');
src:
    url('f1o1n1t1s/B_Titr_Bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('f1o1n1t1s/B_Titr_Bold.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('f1o1n1t1s/B_Titr_Bold.otf') format('opentype'),
    url('f1o1n1t1s/B_Titr_Bold.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

change your code to

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'sommet_roundedregular';
    src: url('sommet_rounded_regular.otf');
    src:
         url('sommet_rounded_regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('sommet_rounded_regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('sommet_rounded_regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('sommet_rounded_regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),  
         url('sommet_rounded_regular-webfont.svg#sommet_roundedregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

why "woff"!?
not need.

---

note to `<mete>`s
Use:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

in head tag.

And end

use unicode

```
<p>\u0200</p> for È
```